# Image upload to filepath using PDO and sql not uploading

Tags: php, sql, image, pdo, upload

I'm trying to upload an image to a file path and I can't seem to get it working. this is code I have used before and all worked fine. I have checked permissions and everything is fine. No idea what I am doing wrong..

Checked all of the permissions and all seem to be OK
Server is capable of uploading via PHP

```
 if (isset($_POST['file'])) {

$targetDir = "../images/gallery-images/";
$fileName = basename($_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$targetFilePath = $targetDir . $fileName;
$fileType = pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');

if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath);
}

if (empty($fileName)) {
    $error = 'All fields are required!';
} else {
        $query = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO gallery gallery_image VALUES ?');
        $query->bindValue(1, $fileName);
        $query->execute();
        header('Location: gallery.php');
    }
}
```

**/* FORM */**

```
<form class="add-new-post" method="POST" action="gallery.php"  enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="" for="featured">Add Image - 500px x 300px:</label>
         <input type="file" class="ml-3" name="file">
    </div>
    <input class="btn btn-sm btn-accent ml-auto" type="submit" value="Add Image" />
</form>
```

Basically nothing happens...

Comment: Please configure PDO to throw exceptions on error and PHP to display or log all errors. That you should warn you about the invalid SQL code.

Comment: `VALUES ?`` not suppose to be `VALUES (?)`

Comment: Turns out if i added a 'name' field to the input button and queried that as  if (isset($_POST['submit'])) it worked perfectly fine..

Answer (score 0):

Check if `file_uploads = off` edit to `file_uploads=On` in `php.ini`

and fix query to be like this

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('INSERT INTO table_name (column1) VALUES (:calories) ');
$sth->bindParam(':calories', $calories);
$sth->execute();
```

and also try to use `strtolower();`

```
$fileType = strtolower(pathinfo($targetFilePath,PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
$allowTypes = array('jpg','png','jpeg','gif','pdf');

if(in_array($fileType, $allowTypes)){
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $targetFilePath);
}
```